# Design pattern - Best place for helper class

Tags: java, spring, design-patterns, structure, helper

I have a question regarding source code structure. What is the package should I allocate the helper classes which implement some logic.

[image]

Here is my source code structure. Let me explain it:

I have many rules when getting information about a flight, such as baggage allowance rule (BaggageAllocationRule.java), meal rule, seat allocation rule...
All above rules have common information that is defined in FlightCommonRule class (extends abstract class Rule).
Then, I have abstract class RuleMatcher that provides functions to lookup matched rules. There are 2 types of RuleMatcher, SingleHitRuleMatcher (returns at most one rule), MultipleHitRuleMatcher (returns multiple rules).

I think that BaggageAllowanceRuleMatcher, SingleHitRuleMatcher, MultipleHitRuleMatcher, RuleMatcher are allocated in the wrong package (model).

How should I restructure the source code?

Comment: https://www.yegor256.com/2014/05/05/oop-alternative-to-utility-classes.html

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any single correct answer. But I would prefer to do it this way. Basically in "com.rule" naming convention, you can have "rule" as your app name (this is your base package). Inside that you can have "model" & "matcher" package. I don't think it is necessary to have "rule" inside "model" package unless you have too many other Model classes which is not related to rule (that shouldn't be the case anyways as you are building a rule service).

```
com.rule.model
      Rule1.class
      Rule2.class

com.rule.matcher
      Matcher1.class
      Matcher2.class
```